# How to loop through the names of installed packages in SLES

Tags: linux, shell, rpm, suse, sles

I want to port my installed packages on a SLES SP1 System to another SLES System without an internet connection. So I got the idea to use

```
rpmrebuild packagename
```

to pack all installed packages back into rpms and then copy those to the other machine.

So I am searching for a way to loop through the names of all installed packages.

Comment: post your code is a start of getting help. Now the possible answer can be too broadly answered.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can always loop through the list of installed packages on any system having RPM package manager by using below shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash 

while read -r package; do echo "This package is $package"; done < <(rpm -qa)
```

Output -

```
This package is ethtool-3.15-2.27.amzn1.x86_64
This package is libXau-1.0.6-4.9.amzn1.x86_64
This package is libXcomposite-0.4.3-4.6.amzn1.x86_64
This package is libblkid-2.23.2-33.28.amzn1.x86_64
....................................................
```

Comment: Why write to a file? `while read -r package; do ...; done < <(rpm -qa)` avoids the overhead, and the need to clean up later.

Comment: (And why assign to `name`, when you already have each value assigned to `package`?)

Comment: Also, the `rm -rf packages.txt` adds no value, since `> packages.txt` will truncate any preexisting content as it is.

Comment: Yes @Charles, I had missed quite a few things. Updated the answer.